# Qt mousePressedEvent called when mouse enter window

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `MainWindow(::QMainWindow)`, I rewrote `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` to track mouse. Everything goes ok except `mousePressEvent`.

When I press mouse left button and move the mouse, `mouseMoveEvent` is called, then I move the mouse out of my window and release mouse left button, after this I move the mouse into my window without left button pressed, `mousePressedEvent` is called. And when I click left button for the first time since mouse entered, `mousePressedEvent` is not called.

**It's weird that mousePressedEvent is called when there is no buttons pressed.**

I wonder if this is the default policy of qt or a bug. How can I overcome this ?

---

After add log to those method, I found that when I move mouse out of window with button pressed, `mouseReleaseEvent` is called automatically while the button is not released.

Additional I am working on mac os 10.11 with Qt 5.4.0

---

Finally I found this is not the default policy of Qt. I have this question because I add a NSView to QtWindow.

Comment: Can't you just detect when the mouse is gone outside and ignore one `mousePressEvent` call since you can't push the button outside and get it back with this state to your window?

Also, what OS, what Qt version?

Comment: I tried, but I can't determine wether mousePressEvent is fired by user clicked or system policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `event(QEvent *curEvent)` public slot ? I worked out the way you said, its working fine. As you release Mouse outside `MainWindow` then you will get `MouseRelese` event, and when you come back in `MainWindow` then **no mousepress event is called**. Please check with below code. I am using `QT on Windows` with `MinGW` compiler.

```
bool MainWindow :: event(QEvent *curEvent)
{
    if(curEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug() << "Mouse Press";
    }

    if(curEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        qDebug() << "Mouse Release";
    }

    if(curEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        qDebug() << "Mouse Move";
    }

    return QWidget::event(curEvent);
}
```

Comment: I have tried. Nothing changed. My MainWindow extends QMainWindow. I am using Qt on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right. 
My problem happened because I add a NSView to my window.
I think I have another question. I will google it first.